I have a function in a nested component in Route /Home , I want to call the same function in route /Login without navigating to Home
What are the possible ways I can call a function from one component that is nested in one route to another route, without navigating
One approach I could think of is passing the fn as props
But what are the other possible approaches

Hi, can you share some more insights on what needs to be done? Can you show some code demonstrating the above issue?
